# First two row addition column-wise in matrix?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have a 10 x 100 `matrix` and I want to add the first two elements of each column together in R, how do I go about this?

I would like it to be separate for each column, e.g. Column 1 would return the sum of first 2 elements in Column 1, Column 2 would return the sum of first 2 elements in Column 2 etc.

Thank you.

Comment: you forgot to tag [tag:java], [tag:c#], [tag:c++]...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51135282/edit) your question to include sample data and expected output. Do you want to sum *only the first two* elements in every column, or *every two* elements? What is the dimension of your output `matrix`? Also review how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: basically I want to create a new matrix (dimension 1x100) from 10x100 matrix but in the new matrix I want the first value to correspond to the sum of the first two elements of column one of the old matrix and so on

Comment: Not clear! How do you collapse 10 rows of your `10x100` matrix into a single row? If you sum only the first 2 rows, you'll end up with a `9x100` matrix; if you sum entries from *every two rows* per column you get a `5x100` matrix. **Please provide sample data and expected output!**

Comment: my matrix x<- matrix(rnorm(1000), nrow=10, ncol=100) and this basically gives me 100 vectors of dimension 10 e.g (x1,x2,x3,...,x10) a hundred times and I need to create a y variable y= x1+x2 for each vector

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` for first two rows of your matrix.
`MARGIN = 2` means `apply` `sum` by column.

```
# create matrix
m <- matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 100)

# apply sum to first two rows of the matrix
y <- apply(m[1:2, ], MARGIN = 2, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `+` operator for addition.

If you matrix is called `m`, then `m[1, ]` is the first row, `m[2, ]` is the second row, and `m[1, ] + m[2, ]` will add the first row to the second row.